# req Properties are null Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a POST method that calls the `next()` function but when I try to access the `res` properties I get `undefined`. If I print:

```
console.log(res)
```

I can see the properties that I need but for some reason trying to access them returns `undefined`.
This is my code:

```
app.post('/login', [function(req, res, next){

req.ID = "hello, world"
next();

}, function(req, res){

  console.log(res) //I can see res.ID I am trying to access in the log
  console.log(res.ID) //undefined
})
```

I have:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

at the very top of my file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've provided you have a syntactical error where you didn't close the array that you've defined your login middleware.

For improved readability and modularity I'd recommend moving your middleware to a function and then pass the function reference to your Express route definition.

```
function loginMiddleware (req, res, next) {
  req.ID = 'Hello World'

  return next()
}

app.post('/login', loginMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.ID) // logs 'Hello World'
})
```